# Socket: send() function returned 'Broken Pipe' error

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, broken-pipe

I am new to socket programming, I am trying to send some packets to server using the `send()` function in C++, but I am always getting a 'Broken pipe' error while sending packets to the server. Could you please help me for the below points?

1. When the `send()` function returns the "Broken pipe" errors?
2. What are the causes for "Broken pipe" errors in socket programming?
3. What will be the solution for "Broken pipe" error from the `send()` function?

Note: I am using named socket to communicate between client and server.

Answer (score 8):

> 1. When `send()` returns the "Broken pipe"  errors

When you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

> 2. What are the causes for "Broken pipe" errors in socket programming

Writing to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

> 3. What will be the solution for "Broken pipe" error from send() function.

Don't write to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

It usually indicates that you have committed a prior application protocol error, so the peer didn't understand you and gave up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, then when do get "Bad file Descriptor" error.

Comment: @K.H.Nagaradder - Most all socket send errors, with the exception of EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK, should be treated as a failed connection and your code should just close the socket handle. If you are getting "Bad file descriptor", it probably means a programming error on your part. Like maybe you already closed the socket or the file handle you are sending on is not a socket.

Comment: @K.H.Nagaradder When you call a system function with a file descriptor that is closed or was never opened. One question at a time thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and figured you can put in MSG_NOSIGNAL as the flag paramether insted of 0 to prefent the send function from throwing a signal if the socket is closed. insted it will return a -1 to show you that sending was not successfull.

```
int rc = send(sockFD, "data", 4, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if (rc == -1) cout << "socket send failed" << endl;
```

Comment: In which case `send()` will return -1 with `errno == EPIPE`, which is consistent with what the OP states. It isn't clear that he's getting a signal rather than an `errno`.