# syscall.Write returns broken pipe while tcp connection establish

Tags: sockets, go

## Background

- To learn network programming, I tried to write raw socket by Golang, did not use `net` module.

## Procedure

- 1. Server binds socket(`syscall.Bind`) and listens(`syscall.Listen`).
- 2. client tries to connect(`syscall.Connect`) and server accepts(`syscall.Accepts`)
- 3. server responses "Hello" to socket by `syscall.Write`.
- 4. client reads socket by `syscall.Read`

then, code is here ->

https://gist.github.com/ryfjwr/21e01fb5e133861b41e981e14ced8672

## Problem

- above **Procedure**, while executing **step 3**, server exists because of `broken pipe`.
- at first, run server

  $ go run tcp-server.go
- then, run client

  $ go run tcp-client.go
- then gets `broken pipe` error.

  $ go run tcp-server.go

  Write Error
  broken pipe
  exit

## Question

- Why `Broken pipe` occurs? Any other reserch thing?

  - I investigated same situation, `When you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.`, but, I triggerd `sleep`, before client exits.
  - source: [c++ - Socket: send() function returned 'Broken Pipe' error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448088/socket-send-function-returned-broken-pipe-error)